# Migrating/moving/upgrading a SharePoint 2007 project and deploying it to SharePoint 2010 with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have a **working project in SharePoint 2007**,

I need to take this project and deploy it to **SharePoint 2010 using visual studio 2010**.

**What would be easiest way to achieve this and where should I start ?**.

I have mainly worked with **SharePoint 2010** so I am not sure how to take a project which works well in SharePoint 2007 and re-deploy it to SharePoint 2010.

**I obviously want to avoid having to re-write the whole project as this would not be ideal**.

Many thanks for any suggestions or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a wsp to make it deployable in Share point 201 then follow this steps
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2010/09/09/updating-a-sharepoint-2007-wsp-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

OR

http://geekswithblogs.net/juanlarios/archive/2011/03/29/upgrading-sharepoint-2007-projects-to-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Let me know the outcome.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks promising. I'll give this a go and will let you know what comes of it.